# Database not writing while statement returns TRUE

Tags: 8

```
public function verify() {
    $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
    $username = $user->get('name')->value;
    $update = 1;
    $verify = 0;

    $mysql = new addressverify_MySql();
    $datestamp = $mysql -> pushVerificationDate($username, $update, $verify);

    if ($datestamp === TRUE) {
        return 'success';
    }
    // All else fails, no record
    return FALSE;
 } } 


class addressverify_MySql {



public /*void*/ function pushVerificationDate(/*string*/ $username, /*bool*/ $verify, /*bool*/ $update) {

    $insert = \Drupal::database()->insert('du_addressverify_verification')
     ->fields([
        'username' => $username,
        'datestamp' => now(),
        'verified' => $verify,
        'updated' => $update,
     ])
     ->execute();

    if (is_numeric($insert))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

As written, this code returns true, however, does not write to the database.   If I comment out the if statement in pushVerificationDate(), it returns false but writes to the database.   I'm at a loss for how to proceed with this to return true AND write to the database. I have a feeling it's something silly that I'm missing, but can't seem to find it.  Any input would be helpful!

Comment: Does your table have an auoincrement column? If not you should ignore the return value from execute, it’s not reliable. A PDOException will be raised if there’s a problem, just catch that instead

Comment: I don't understand why most of this code is the way it is - but have you debugged and looked at what `$insert` is for both true and false cases to know the code is correct?

Comment: Yes my table has an auto increment column @Clive